# XSL stylesheet keeps Firefox from recognising DTD-defined ids

Tags: html, xslt

I want a client-side XSL-transformed document with elements targettable (jumpable to) by #foo (URL fragments). Problem is, as soon as I attach the simplest XSL stylesheet, Firefox stops scrolling to the elements. Here's simple code:

test.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='test.xsl'?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [<!ATTLIST bar id ID #REQUIRED>]>
<foo xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en-GB'>
<html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/>
<bar id='baz'>Baf.</bar>
</foo>
```

test.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:template match='/'>
<xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As soon as I uncomment the stylesheet line, /test.xml#baz does nothing. As though the transformation somehow loses some data about elements' identification.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I've had the same problems using IE explorer (don't ask!) . I'll be interested to see if someone can explain and help us correct this. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Well the XSLT/XPath data model does not include any DTD and thus your result tree that XSLT creates is a copy of the input without the DTD, thus there is no definition of any `ID` attributes in the result tree and Firefox has no way of establishing to which element with which attribute `#some-id`  refers.

Usually if you use client-side XSLT in the browser the target format is (X)HTML or SVG or a mix of both where `id` attributes are known by the browser implementation without needing a DTD. If you want to transform to a result format unknown to the browser then I don't think there is a way to use DTDs for the result tree in Firefox/Mozilla. And I am not sure whether they ever implemented `xml:id` support so that you could use that instead of defining your own `ID` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Honnen's mention of XHTML resulted in experimentation during which I found out that setting the target element's namespace to XHTML's, xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', does the trick. It doesn't seem very clean, but it doesn't seem as grave as, for instance, setting the whole doctype to XHTML's. So text.xml is now:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='test.xsl'?>
<foo xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en-GB'>
<html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/><html:br/>
<html:bar id='baz'>Baf.</html:bar>
</foo>
```

Also relevant might be http://xmlplease.com/xhtmlxhtml I found.

Thanks, all.